# What is your method of “folksonomy” tagging for files on your local machine?

Tags: file-management, tags

Way back in the days when "delicious" was just "del.icio.us", I had assumed that everyone had finally caught on that [Ontology is overrated](http://www.shirky.com/writings/ontology_overrated.html).

I can tag on-line web links, blog posts, questions on stackoverflow.com, and all kinds of web-centric miscellany, but this very basic concept still seems to be missing (or hideously crippled) in Windows?

If you use "tagging" for your local files, what do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use tagging. I use search. A good search engine built right into Windows since Vista, and it has rarely failed me.

Comment: That makes sense, but how do you search when the content is mp3 files or images? Tagging allows you to actually attach descriptions to non-editable files.

Comment: @dreftymac: `Cygwin: find /path/to/base/dir -type f -name *.mp3 | grep fileNameRegEx`; or create a index of mp3 files with `locate32.exe`.

Comment: Problem is when you start to get a thousand hits, because you couldn't narrow down that nice query of yours... But then most often it works just fine

Comment: +1 for Windows search.  Could not live without it.  No need to add any extra metadata.

Answer (score 2):

1. Vista has some support - [**Tag files and save searches in Windows Vista**](http://lifehacker.com/232891/tag-files-and-save-searches-in-windows-vista)

   - [**TaggedFrog**](http://lunarfrog.com/) for XP - [**Add tags to files in Windows XP using TaggedFrog**](http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/tag-files-windows/)
   - [**Tagging files in Windows XP (and why you’ll ditch Google Desktop)**](http://ceitl.zanestate.edu/blog/archives/2006/02/tagging-files-in-windows-xp-and-why-youll-ditch-google-desktop/)

Interestingly, none of these are my methods.
I use [**locate32.exe**](http://www.locate32.net/) if I have to find files.
Gave up on windows indexing a long time back.
I might even do a `Cygwin`, `bash`, `find` and even `grep` to get a file.

Comment: +1 on cygwin and bash ... they are painful to use on windows, but a lot less painful than not having them at all

Comment: @nik, have you used Windows search in Win 7?  Why did you give it up?  It allows you to index files, mail, etc and search by field names such as From:, to:, & date.